# Overloading BindingList<T> of parent property with a subclass of T

Tags: c#, oop

I am having some trouble with an idea that at its simplest seems like it should work.

I am trying to overload a Property of Type `BindingList<T>` in a subclass with a `BindingList` of `<subclasss T>`.  There are ways I can get around this but it seems the 'nicest' way would be without any direct casting.  I have tried a bunch of options and have some solutions but I am not particularly happy with any of them.

Is there a best approach to this?  A *simple* code example might be the best descriptor
In this example below, I want to derive a fruitbowl to contain only apples but use the same property name to access this `BindingList<>` of Apples (in the case of the subclass; generic fruit in the case of the Super class).

--------Example-------

```
class Fruit{}
class Apple: Fruit {}

class FruitBowl
{
  protected BindingList<Fruit>  m_aFruits;

  public BindingList<Fruit> Fruits
  {
    get {return m_aFruits;}
  }
}

class AppleBowl : FruitBowl
{
  public BindingList<Apple> Fruits
  {
    get {return m_aFruits;}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're attempting to do is known as Co/Contra Variance.  Unfortunately this is not supported on concrete types in C# (available on interfaces only for C# 4.0).  Given the implementation of BindingList<T> it is not possible to do what you want and maintain only a single list.

You can attempt to fake this in several ways.  One way to get around this is to only use IEnumerable<T> on the sub class.  In this case a simple LINQ query will do the trick.

```
class AppleBowl : FruitBowl
{
  public IEnumerableApple> TypedFruits
  {
    get {return base.Fruits.Cast<Apple>();}
  }
}
```

Comment: His example is a little ambiguous, but I don't think he is necessarily meaning to attempt co/contravariance here. He stated that he does want AppleBowl *instance* to hold only apples, so there doesn't have to be a type change involved.

Comment: @Rex it may not be exactly what he's looking for but in order to achieve his goals it's what he'll need.  There has to be a type change involved if he wants to return the same concrete class with 2 different generic arguments

Answer (score 1):

```
class FruitBowl<T> where T : Fruit //this requires T to inherit from Fruit
{
    protected BindingList<T> Fruits;
}

class AppleBowl : FruitBowl<Apple>
{
    //AppleBowl will have an inherited property Fruits 
    //of type BindingList<Apple>
}
```

Comment: +1 - Also, whack a "where T : Fruit" constraint on your FruitBowl<T> for even more type safety.

Comment: @Matt was typing it as you added the comment :)